# Scheduling a Post in wordpress WITH CODE (Not wordpress backend.)

Tags: php, wordpress, post, schedule

How can I update a post to publish in the future? so far I have this:

```
$postAmends = array(
                        'ID'            =>  $newID,
                        'edit_date'     =>  true,
                    );
                    $postAmends['post_title'] = $post->post_title.' In the future!'; 

                    //Sort the date and deadline.:
                    switch ($postMeta[' _task_repeat'][0])
                    {
                        case 'daily':
                            $postAmends['post_date'] = date('o-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($post->post_date.' +2 minutes'));
                            update_post_meta($newID, ' _task_billing_deadline', date('F j, Y', strtotime($postMeta[' _task_billing_deadline'][0].' +1 day')));
                            break;

      wp_update_post( $postAmends );
```

This code works but it doesn't schedule the post only makes it pending and never publishes it.

I have searched high and low and all I can find is people describing how to do it in the backend of wordpress, not quite what I need xD

EDIT: Also setting

```
'post_status'   => 'future'
```

just publishes the post

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-scheduling/, may be it'll help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Thanks for that was a good read. However, is there anyway to utilizing the existing functions that wordpress uses to schedule a post instead of writing my own function that is called to publish the post?

Comment: Post a question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, definitely you'll get some good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question. Although the question if from a long time ago, I am posing the solution, as there is no answer and someone else might find this useful.

You can use the **wp_update_post** function to schedule a post but you have to send both **post_date** and **post_date_gmt** as part of the post array/object. WordPress will handle the rest. Based on the post date it will set the post status to publish or schedule.

```
$post->ID = $id;
$post->post_date = $publish_date;
$post->post_date_gmt = $publish_date;
wp_update_post($post);
```

or

```
$post['ID'] = $id;
$post['post_date'] = $publish_date;
$post['post_date_gmt'] = $publish_date;
wp_update_post($post);
```